# How to crack my MacBook’s password?

Tags: macos, password-recovery, dictionary, brute-force

I forgot my laptop password. I tried a lot of passwords but my laptop does not accept it.

I searched the internet for possible answers, and I've come across the "Brute-Force or Dictionary force" method.

Should I use some type of USB, where a Brute-Force or Dictionary force software is installed and crack the laptop password?

I have MacBook with macOS Sierra operating system.

Comment: What password exactly are we talking about? Your Windows account password? Are you using a Microsoft (online) account or is it a local account? Are you aware of any disk encryption you might be using?

Comment: It's probably more easy and faster to hack your *brain*... did you already relax, or meditate with no intention of remembering your forgotten password? Memory might reemerge "out of the blue"... or at least some hints (start characters, length, characters to exclude from a brute-force search) you can use when recovering it with technical means. Strictly speaking, "forgetting a password" is not a *technical* problem, thus not necessarily requiring a technical solution ;)

Comment: You can't install anything to crack it… because you don't have the passowrd needed to install anything. It highly depends on exactly **what** is locked & how it is managed. If, for instance, you have a T2 Macbook with secure boot enabled, then you will need to take it to an Apple Store with proof of ownership. Nothing, literally nothing, else will get you in. You now own a brick.

Comment: Additionally [again depending on the lock method] a timer will kick in after 3 failed attempts, which will get longer between re-tries until the time between attempts reaches months or years.

Comment: Meditation is a good option.-----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have your Firevault key or you connected it to an Apple ID, you're in trouble. If one of those is true, you can use the official Apple support page which I linked below. Also, if you're fine with getting rid of your apps, I'm pretty sure you can use recovery mode or something to back up your files and then factory reset your Laptop.

Helpful links:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860
- https://beebom.com/how-reset-mac-password-macos-sierra/

You might have better luck if you try asking in the [Ask Different Stack Exchange site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).